# JMS Serializer self referenced objects with other details level

Tags: php, symfony, jms-serializer

I work with some related objects, and try to get to the point what is the best way to manage serialisation for them (I use JMS Serializer) at different level depends on an attribute.

My case:

I have company object, with plenty of attributes that is used itself as API resource [`list` and `details` groups].
Now I created an object called **card**, where I refer to the related company, with some additional data, like score etc. But also I want to store some other companies suggestion, as it is part of the card as well. This is how the class looks like:

```
class Card
{
/**
 * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
 */
protected $company;

/**
 * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
 */
protected $score;

/**
 * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
 */
protected $type;


/**
 * @Serializer\Groups({"details"})
 */
protected $suggestedCards;

}
```

where **$company** in a Company object, and **$suggestedCompanies** is an collection of Company objects. Company object has also groups configured, so all data I want are collected.

With that code, both $company and $suggestedCompanies contains all data that is allowed for *details* group, but my expectations are to display only some part of data (like *id, name, city*, so, not ID only) for suggestions.

The problem that I found is that even if I try to create different groups for those properties (`suggested_companies`), they will still appear with all data from details, as I still use this group to get primary company data.

---

I solved it in a way, that for *suggestedCompanies* I had created a separate object, where I pass all required fields in the constructor, so I can set own serialisation rules for that.

It works pretty OK, I'm just wondering is there maybe a better solution for this problem.

Comment: If it's just about serialization and no nesting, I would probably resort to a custom method that returns an array with `@VirtualProperty` annotation.